# Switching PayPal from sandbox to live results in a null paypal.billingAgreement.execute(token, {}, (error, billingAgreement) billing agreement object

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-subscriptions

Working flawlessly in 'sandbox' mode with ENVIRONMENT set to 'DEV' but when i switch to 'PROD' my paypal.billingAgreement.execute(token, {}, (error, billingAgreement) callback is called with billingAgreement as null which breaks the rest of the execution. Is this a paypal account issue? What would cause them .execute to return a null billingAgreement?

Is there a minimum subscription amount? I tried 5 cents and $1 for testing purposes.

Do I not have the correct paypal permissions, or am I missing some additional step required for live transactions? My account has permissions to do subscriptions for live.

My primary email for my paypal account has changed and my apps and credentials rest apps have their PayPal account set as my old email (cant find a way to change this) but I tried swapping back to my old email and it still didnt work.

```
// Configure your environment
    if (ENVIRONMENT === 'DEV') {
        // ## DEVELOPMENT:
        paypal.configure({
            mode: 'sandbox', // sandbox or live
            client_id: functions.config().paypal.client_id_dev, // run: firebase functions:config:set paypal.client_id="yourPaypalClientID"
            client_secret: functions.config().paypal.client_secret_dev // run: firebase functions:config:set paypal.client_secret="yourPaypalClientSecret"
        });
    }
    else if (ENVIRONMENT === 'PROD') {
        // ## PRODUCTION:
        paypal.configure({
            mode: 'live', // sandbox or live
            client_id: functions.config().paypal.client_id_prod, // run: firebase functions:config:set paypal.client_id="yourPaypalClientID"
            client_secret: functions.config().paypal.client_secret_prod // run: firebase functions:config:set paypal.client_secret="yourPaypalClientSecret"
        });
    }
```

The `paypal.billingPlan.create` and `paypal.billingPlan.update` work fine, but the  `paypal.billingPlan.execute` does not:

```
  paypal.billingAgreement.execute(token, {}, (error, billingAgreement) => {
        console.log("EXECUTING THiS AGREEMENT in billingAgreement.execute:");
        console.log(billingAgreement);
        if (error) {
            console.error(JSON.stringify(error));
            //...
```

and the logs:

7:18:35.488 AM
info
process
PROCESSING THE PAYMENT NOW:

7:18:40.728 AM
info
process
EXECUTING THiS AGREEMENT in billingAgreement.execute:

7:18:40.730 AM
info
process
null  <-- the billingAgreement in the execute callback is now null.

7:18:40.730 AM
warning 
process
{"response":{"name":"SUBSCRIPTION_UNMAPPED_ERROR","message":"Subscription start date should be greater than current date","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.billing-agreements#errors","debug_id":"3c2f5d0ecbb3d","httpStatusCode":400},"httpStatusCode":400}

Comment: Do you set your start date correctly?

Comment: The whole object is null thats why its probably complaining about start date, because the date is null as the whole object is null - no complaints about my date setting in 'sandbox' mode and I am just using paypals exact spec code from their github example:     let isoDate = new Date();
    isoDate.setSeconds(isoDate.getSeconds() + 4);
    isoDate.toISOString().slice(0, 19) + 'Z';